# Zipping free monad transformers

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers, free-monad

The `streaming` package offers [a `zipsWith` function](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/streaming-0.2.2.0/docs/Streaming.html#v:zipsWith)

```
zipsWith
  :: (Monad m, Functor h)
  => (forall x y. f x -> g y -> h (x, y))
  -> Stream f m r -> Stream g m r -> Stream h m r
```

and a slightly more streamlined version,

```
zipsWith'
  :: Monad m
  => (forall x y p. (x -> y -> p) -> f x -> g y -> h p)
  -> Stream f m r -> Stream g m r -> Stream h m r
```

These can be adapted very easily to [`FreeT`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/free-5.1/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Free.html#t:FreeT) from the `free` package. But that package offers [another version](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/free-5.1/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Free-Church.html#t:FT) of the free monad transformer:

```
newtype FT f m a = FT
  { runFT
      :: forall r.
         (a -> m r)
      -> (forall x. (x -> m r) -> f x -> m r)
      -> m r }
```

There is also a third (rather simple) formulation:

```
newtype FF f m a = FF
  { runFF
      :: forall n. Monad n
      => (forall x. f x -> n x)  -- A natural transformation
      -> (forall x. m x -> n x)  -- A monad morphism
      -> n a }
```

It is possible to convert back and forth between `FreeT` and either `FT` or `FF`, which offers an indirect way to implement `zipsWith` and its relatives for `FF` and `FT`. But that seems quite unsatisfying. I seek a more direct solution.

The problem seems related to the challenge of zipping lists using folds. This has been addressed in a paper, [Coroutining Folds with Hyperfunctions](https://arxiv.org/abs/1309.5135), by Launchbury et al, as well as a [blog post](https://doisinkidney.com/posts/2016-04-17-folding-two-at-once.html) by Donnacha Kidney. Neither of these are terribly simple, and I have no idea how they might be adapted to the `FT` or `FF` contexts.

---

As I've looked into this problem, I've realized that `streaming` should really offer some more powerful versions. The simplest would be something like

```
zipsWith''
  :: Monad m
  => (forall x y p. (x -> y -> p) -> f x -> g y -> h p)
  -> Stream f m r -> Stream g m s -> Stream h m (Either r s)
```

but a more powerful option would include the remainder:

```
zipsWithRemains
  :: Monad m
  => (forall x y p. (x -> y -> p) -> f x -> g y -> h p)
  -> Stream f m r
  -> Stream g m s
  -> Stream h m (Either (r, Stream g m s)
                        (f (Stream f m r), s))
```

I would guess that `zipsWith''` would be no harder than `zipsWith'`, but that `zipsWithRemains` might be a bigger challenge in the context of `FT` or `FF`, since the remainder will presumably have to be reconstituted somehow.

#### Note

Since there was some confusion previously, let me mention that I am *not* looking for help writing `zipsWithRemains` for `Stream` or `FreeT`; I am only looking for help with the functions on `FT` and `FF`.

Comment: In `zipsWith''` and `zipsWithRemains`, what happens if both streams finish at the same time?

Comment: @danidiaz, if the first stream ends, we return its result immediately. That's necessary to get left catch for `mplus`, which is defined using `zipsWith'`. `zipsWithRemains` helps clarify that somewhat with its asymmetrical result: note the `f (Stream f m r)` as opposed to the `Stream g m s`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I implemented `zipsWith'`, `zipsWith''` and `zipsWithRemains` for `FT`. My implementation closely mirrors the implementation of `zipWith` from [this blog post](https://doisinkidney.com/posts/2016-04-17-folding-two-at-once.html).

First, notice that, given `zipsWith'`, implementing `zipsWith''` is trivial:

```
zipsWith''
  :: (Functor f, Functor g, Monad m)
  => (forall x y p. (x -> y -> p) -> f x -> g y -> h p)
  -> FT f m r
  -> FT g m s
  -> FT h m (Either r s)
zipsWith'' phi a b = zipsWith' phi (Left <$> a) (Right <$> b)
```

So let's implement `zipsWith'`.

Begin with an expanded and annotated version of `zipWith` using folds:

```
newtype RecFold a r = RecFold { runRecFold :: BFold a r }
type AFold a r = RecFold a r -> r
type BFold a r = a -> AFold a r -> r

zipWith
  :: forall f g a b c.
  (Foldable f, Foldable g)
  => (a -> b -> c)
  -> f a
  -> g b
  -> [c]
zipWith c a b = loop af bf where
  af :: AFold a [c]
  af = foldr ac ai a
  ai :: AFold a [c]
  ai _ = []
  ac :: a -> AFold a [c] -> AFold a [c]
  ac ae ar bl = runRecFold bl ae ar
  bf :: BFold a [c]
  bf = foldr bc bi b
  bi :: BFold a [c]
  bi _ _ = []
  bc :: b -> BFold a [c] -> BFold a [c]
  bc be br ae ar = c ae be : loop ar br
  loop :: AFold a [c] -> BFold a [c] -> [c]
  loop al bl = al (RecFold bl)
```

And turn it into `zipsWith'`:

```
newtype RecFold f m r = RecFold { runRecFold :: BFold f m r }
type AFold f m r = m (RecFold f m r -> r)
type BFold f m r = m (f (AFold f m r) -> r)

zipsWith'
  :: forall f g h m r.
  (Monad m, Functor f, Functor g)
  => (forall x y p. (x -> y -> p) -> f x -> g y -> h p)
  -> FT f m r
  -> FT g m r
  -> FT h m r
zipsWith' phi a b = loop af bf where
  af :: AFold f m (FT h m r)
  af = runFT a ai ac
  ai :: r -> AFold f m (FT h m r)
  ai r = return $ const $ return r
  ac :: (x -> AFold f m (FT h m r)) -> f x -> AFold f m (FT h m r)
  ac am ae = return $ effect . fmap ($ (fmap am ae)) . runRecFold
  bf :: BFold f m (FT h m r)
  bf = runFT b bi bc
  bi :: r -> BFold f m (FT h m r)
  bi r = return $ const $ return r
  bc :: (x -> BFold f m (FT h m r)) -> g x -> BFold f m (FT h m r)
  bc bm be = return $ wrap . flip (phi loop) (fmap bm be)
  loop :: AFold f m (FT h m r) -> BFold f m (FT h m r) -> FT h m r
  loop av bv = effect $ fmap ($ (RecFold bv)) av
```

Here, two auxiliary functions are used: `effect` and `wrap`.

```
effect :: Monad m => m (FT f m r) -> FT f m r
effect m = FT $ \hr hy -> m >>= \r -> runFT r hr hy

wrap :: f (FT f m r) -> FT f m r
wrap s = FT $ \hr hy -> hy (\v -> runFT v hr hy) s
```

Note that the result could be any monad for which these functions are implemented.

To implement `zipsWithRemains`, start by implementing `zipWithRemains` for ordinary `Foldable`s:

```
data ListWithTail a b = Nil b | Cons a (ListWithTail a b)
type Result a b c = ListWithTail c (Either [b] (a, [a]))
newtype RecFold a b c = RecFold { runRecFold :: BFold a b c }
type AFold a b c = (RecFold a b c -> Result a b c, [a])
type BFold a b c = (a -> AFold a b c -> Result a b c, [b])

zipWithRemains
  :: forall f g a b c.
  (Foldable f, Foldable g)
  => (a -> b -> c)
  -> f a
  -> g b
  -> Result a b c
zipWithRemains c a b = loop af bf where
  af :: AFold a b c
  af = foldr ac ai a
  ai :: AFold a b c
  ai = (\bl -> Nil $ Left $ snd (runRecFold bl), [])
  ac :: a -> AFold a b c -> AFold a b c
  ac ae ar = (\bl -> fst (runRecFold bl) ae ar, ae : snd ar)
  bf :: BFold a b c
  bf = foldr bc bi b
  bi :: BFold a b c
  bi = (\ae ar -> Nil $ Right (ae, snd ar), [])
  bc :: b -> BFold a b c -> BFold a b c
  bc be br = (\ae ar -> Cons (c ae be) (loop ar br), be : snd br)
  loop :: AFold a b c -> BFold a b c -> Result a b c
  loop al bl = fst al (RecFold bl)
```

Here, the result of a fold is not a function but a 2-tuple containing a function and a value. The latter is used to handle the "remains" case.

This can also be adapted to `FT`:

```
type Result f g h m r s = FT h m (Either (r, FT g m s) (f (FT f m r), s))
newtype RecFold f g h m r s = RecFold { runRecFold :: BFold f g h m r s }
type AFold f g h m r s = m (RecFold f g h m r s -> Result f g h m r s, FT f m r)
type BFold f g h m r s = m (f (AFold f g h m r s) -> Result f g h m r s, FT g m s)

zipsWithRemains
  :: forall f g h m r s.
  (Monad m, Functor f, Functor g)
  => (forall x y p. (x -> y -> p) -> f x -> g y -> h p)
  -> FT f m r
  -> FT g m s
  -> Result f g h m r s
zipsWithRemains phi a b = loop af bf where
  af :: AFold f g h m r s
  af = runFT a ai ac
  ai :: r -> AFold f g h m r s
  ai r = return (return . Left . (r,) . effect . fmap snd . runRecFold, return r)
  ac :: (x -> AFold f g h m r s) -> f x -> AFold f g h m r s
  ac am ae = return (effect . fmap (($ (fmap am ae)) . fst) . runRecFold, wrap $ fmap (effect . fmap snd . am) ae)
  bf :: BFold f g h m r s
  bf = runFT b bi bc
  bi :: s -> BFold f g h m r s
  bi r = return (return . Right . (,r) . fmap (effect . fmap snd), return r)
  bc :: (x -> BFold f g h m r s) -> g x -> BFold f g h m r s
  bc bm be = return (wrap . flip (phi loop) (fmap bm be), wrap $ fmap (effect . fmap snd . bm) be)
  loop :: AFold f g h m r s -> BFold f g h m r s -> Result f g h m r s
  loop av bv = effect $ fmap (($ (RecFold bv)) . fst) av
```

I wish Haskell had local types!

This probably answers the question for `FT`. Regarding `FF`: this type is designed such that to do anything with it, you first have to convert it to some other monad. So, the question is, which one? It is possible to convert it to `Stream` or `FreeT`, and use the functions for those types. It is also possible to convert it to `FT` and use the above implementations on it. Is there a monad better suited for implementing `zipsWith`? Maybe.

Comment: Hooray! I think I have a reasonably decent intuition for what your `Fold` types are about, but I get pretty lost in the `zipWith` and `zipsWith'` helper functions. Do you think you might be able to add a few comments among them, and perhaps give them more evocative names?

Comment: I should have realized that `zipsWith''` could be gotten for free from `zipsWith'` in the `FT` case, thanks to the way the return value is handled there. For `Stream` or `FreeT`, that would be expensive! I'm quite curious how well your implementation is likely to be optimized compared to the naive one; I'll have to play around with that.

Answer (score 1):

Applying a bit of [Coyoneda](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/kan-extensions-5.2/docs/Data-Functor-Coyoneda.html) to [abacabadabacaba's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53556266/1477667) and doing some juggling yields an implementation that avoids `Functor f` and `Functor g` constraints. If those functors have expensive `fmap`s, this may improve performance. I doubt it's actually better in typical situations where `f` and `g` are things like `(,) a`. I also still don't properly understand what any of this does.

```
type AFold f m r = m (RecFold f m r -> r)
newtype Fish f m r = Fish {unFish :: forall x. (x -> AFold f m r) -> f x -> r}
type BFold f m r = m (Fish f m r)
newtype RecFold f m r = RecFold { runRecFold :: BFold f m r }

zipsWith'
  :: forall f g h m r.
  Monad m
  => (forall x y p. (x -> y -> p) -> f x -> g y -> h p)
  -> FT f m r
  -> FT g m r
  -> FT h m r
zipsWith' phi a b = loop af bf where
  af :: AFold f m (FT h m r)
  af = runFT a ai ac

  ai :: r -> AFold f m (FT h m r)
  ai r = return $ const $ return r

  ac :: (x -> AFold f m (FT h m r)) -> f x -> AFold f m (FT h m r)
  ac am ae = return $ (lift >=> \(Fish z) -> z am ae) . runRecFold

  bf :: BFold f m (FT h m r)
  bf = runFT b bi bc

  bi :: r -> BFold f m (FT h m r)
  bi r = return $ Fish $ \_ _ -> return r

  bc :: (x -> BFold f m (FT h m r)) -> g x -> BFold f m (FT h m r)
  bc bm be = return $ Fish $ \xa z -> wrap $ phi (\q -> loop (xa q) . bm) z be

  loop :: AFold f m (FT h m r) -> BFold f m (FT h m r) -> FT h m r
  loop av bv = lift av >>= ($ (RecFold bv))
```